# How to synchronise a part or full project store on git?

Tags: git

I use git to store a program. I would like to propose to other user would like to clone the project to retrieve a version with the pdf included or in another case without the pdf files ? Is it possible on a branch to set such situation ?
Regards,

Comment: Is this .pdf file created by the build system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with branching is that eventually, you will have to merge one of them, if you're ok with that I suppose you could create a without_pdf branch and a with_pdf branch, or create another repo that doesn't include the pdf.